# Jenkins chef-plugin not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, chef-infra

I am trying to use this plugin https://github.com/melezhik/chef-plugin

I have Jenkins running on tomcat7 in an AWS instance. I installed the plugin via the jenkins 'Manage plugins' UI.

But when I click on 'Run chef client on remote host', I get nothing. The fields that should pop up to allow me to put in details about my ssh-key and other details are not displayed.

Has anyone else experienced this? Are there any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but after a few days and restarting my server, the fields appeared.